# How to assign new value to an Option<Box<_>> variable?

Tags: rust

I am writing a tree in Rust and I want to implement a function:`left` which can turn a tree's root into the tree's root's left child.
Here is my code:

```
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    left: Option<Box<Node>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

struct Tree {
    root: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

enum Error {
    DuplicateValue,
    NotFound,
    EmptyTree
}

impl Tree {
    fn left(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        match self.root {
            Option::None => return Err(Error::EmptyTree),
            Option::Some(ref mut node) => {
                *node = node.left.as_ref().unwrap();
                return Ok(())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the error says

```
mismatched types
expected struct `Box<Node>`
found reference `&Box<Node>`
```

I have tried many methods and look up a lot of information but I still cannot fix this. I think it is a very simple thing in C, just like:

```
*root = *(root->left);
```

but why is it so hard in Rust? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please put the full error from `cargo check`, not your IDE.

Comment: Nit: `Option::None` and `Option::Some` can be just `None` and `Some` (they're in the prelude).

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful for you to read [a walkthrough of an implementation of a similar data structure](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html) that explains very well which difficulties you will meet, why is it so, and how to do what you wanted to do in idiomatic Rust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your code looks like it throws away the whole right branch and the root node when calling `left`, i.e. you aren't concerned with the original root (it will be dropped after the assignment), you can simply `take` the left node out of the `Option`:

```
impl Tree {
    fn left(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        match self.root {
            Option::None => Err(Error::EmptyTree),
            Option::Some(ref mut node) => {
                *node = node.left.take().unwrap();
                Ok(())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d4c0220f2c69ae656ff99f5921f6ba46)

Note however that this will panic if the left subtree is empty. If you want to make `self` empty in this case, you want to replace the whole `Option`, not the value inside it. In this case, you have to first do the matching, return early in the empty case, and only then, after the `root` is no longer borrowed, do the replacement:

```
impl Tree {
    fn left(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        let node = match self.root {
            Option::None => return Err(Error::EmptyTree),
            Option::Some(ref mut node) => node.left.take(),
        };
        self.root = node;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a little explanation to why this is problematic in general will be good.

Comment: "this" = mutable linked structures, here?

Comment: No, why it is hard in Rust to do what the C code does easily: take the ownership of a mutable reference and assign it to itself after modification.

Comment: @BlackBeans above already linked it, but here it is again: [Learning Rust Using Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html).  This explains it at length with lots of examples as to how, why, and when you should and shouldn't do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to replace the entire `Option` in `self.root`, not just the value inside the `Some()` (so that even when `left` is `None`, you don't panic but assign it to `self.root`).

The second problem you're facing is that you have to *move the `left` branch out from the old root* in order to be able to *give* its ownership to `self.root`. Normally, you wouldn't be able to do that, since you only have a mutable reference. Fortunately `Option::take()` is here to help: it lets you take ownership of a value in a `&mut Option`, changing it to `None`.

Now that you own the old tree, you can easily assign its left subtree to `self.root`.

Finally, instead of the `match` thing you had, you can just convert the `Option` into a `Result` via `Option::ok_or()` and short-circuit or extract the value with `?`:

```
fn left(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let old_root = self.root.take().ok_or(Error::EmptyTree)?;
    self.root = old_root.left;
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `clone()` with `#[derive(Clone)]`

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    left: Option<Box<Node>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

struct Tree {
    root: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

enum Error {
    DuplicateValue,
    NotFound,
    EmptyTree
}

impl Tree {
    fn left(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        match self.root {
            Option::None => return Err(Error::EmptyTree),
            Option::Some(ref mut node) => {
                *node = node.left.clone().unwrap();
                return Ok(())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cloning something which can be moved does not fit well with Rust.

Comment: @prog-fh, please note that we're cloning a ref, not node itself

Comment: What do you mean by "cloning a ref"? Cloning `Box<T>` necessarily clones `T`, that's the consequence of single ownership semantics.

Comment: @Cerberus, oops you're right. I think I didn't fully grasp the ownership approach yet. https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-rusts-box-t-clone-implementation-requires-t-to-be-clone/61592